# What is an Ideal Gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I have read that there are no molecular interactions between the molecules of a gas, neither attractive forces nor repulsive. But how does that makes it an Ideal Gas.

What are the effects of these interactions otherwise ?

Answer (score 2):

One important point is that interactions between the molecules would result in a different gas law, i.e. $PV=nRT$ would not hold anymore. Calculating the gas law from a given model of the interactions is quite difficult. On the experimental side, we know that the van der Waals equation,

$$\left(P+a\left(\frac{n}{V}\right)^2\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT,$$

is a better fit for real gases. The coefficient $a$ can be argued to be the result of the attractive interactions between the particles (the coefficient $b$ is the result of taking into account the size of the molecules). See [1] for a derivation but you would need quite a bit of knowledge in Statistical Physics to make sense of it.

[1] Terrell L. Hill. Derivation of the complete van der Waals’ equation from statistical mechanics. Journal of Chemical Education, 25(6):347, 1948.

Answer (score 1):

An **ideal gas** is a simplification that is accurate, for instance, for the everyday atmospheric gas you find in the Earth. The approximation is only valid when the pressure is small and the gas particles can be supposed to have a negligible volume.

If those particles have a negligible volume and their pressure is small, it is as if they did not have interactions ones with the others. That is why you have been told that and that makes the problem far easier to treat: if one had to consider the interactions between the particles, the derivation of the relation between the different properties of the gas would not be that simple and there are other equations that consider these other cases.